# Rounding to nearest

Tags: binary, floating-point, rounding-error

I have the number `0.101` in binary. I want to round it to 2 places after the radix point using the algorithm `rounding to the nearest`. Here is how I do it.

If I want to have two places, then I will have one of the two possible resulting numbers: `0.10` or `0.11`. Let's see how by how much each is different from the original:

1) 0.101 - 0.10 = 0.11

2) 0.101 - 0.11 = 0.10

The second one gives us less difference then the first, so using the algorithm `rounding to the nearest`, `0.101` should be rounded to `0.11`. Is this how the algorithm works?

Comment: Both are equally near: difference is 0.001 in both cases. So you need a tie-breaking rule. Unfortunately there is more than one in use. Does the context tell you which one to use?

Comment: @almagest, thanks, no, no context. I'm just trying to understand how the rounding works. Maybe you could provide an example of rounding for the fraction which results in different differences?

Comment: Your subtractions are wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes, I know that now. I was just thinking that they could be subtracted as in integers: `101-10` and `101-11`. As it turns the different logic should be applied

Comment: @Maximus: they can be subtracted like integers: `101-100=001`, `101-110=-001`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thanks for the suggestion, you just saved me some time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your differences are wrong: `0.101 - 0.10 = 0.001` etc. Second rounding to nearest must be completed with a tie breaking rule if there are two representable numbers with the same difference to the number to be rounded;
in your case both candidate numbers are $\pm 1/8$ from the original number:

```
0.101 - 0.10 =  0.001 = 1/8
0.101 - 0.11 = -0.001 = -1/8
```

Normally we would use  *round to nearest even* (i.e. take the number with the least significant bit $0$) and in your case the result would be `0.10` because `0.11` is odd (the last bit is $1$).

Comment: thanks, can you please provide an example for that _rounding to nearest must be completed with a tie breaking rule_?

Comment: Your numbers **are** an example. The tie-breaking rule is needed if there are
two representable floating point numbers with the same distance to the number,
which shall be rounded. This is like the situation: you want to round the
decimal $2.5$  to the next integer. The possible candidates $2$ and $3$ have the same distance $0.5$. Rounding to nearest even gives $2.$

Comment: Yes, I understand the principles in decimal. I was trying to make an example where the two numbers give unequal difference. Is my logic correct then? Can you please provide a short example of such case in you answer?

Comment: Just editied the answer to include some of your suggestions.

Comment: I was hoping to see the example where the difference is not equal, but I think maybe I should ask another question